# Как подсветить активный элемент ListView?(RecyclerView)

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Думал все тривиально, но не могу решить. есть такой лист вью

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при нажатии на картинку, открывается определенный фрагмент снизу, а элемент подсвечивается. Как подменить айтемы и подсветить я знаю примерно, а вот как определить какой активный?
1. я нажал на первый - подсветил.
2. нажал на второй - первый стал не подсвеченный а второй подсветил и тд.
3. удалил активный  подсвеченный - должен подсветиться первый в списке.

как это реализовать? куда и в какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, во-первых нужно поменять `choiceMode`, который, по-умолчанию стоит none.

Затем, выставить `listSelector`. Тут ты можешь указать не только цвет, но и картинку, если нужно.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="твой цвет"/>
```

UPD:
перечитал вопрос)) Ща дополню)

Если у вас возможен выбор только одного элемента, то ListView сам будет хранить position выделенного элемента. Все что нужно - это вызвать [getSelectedView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getSelectedView()), который вернет вам выделенный View. Либо null, если ничего выделено не было. Еще есть [getCheckedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition())

Comment: это не обычный ListView  а RecyclerView